# Nethereum C# automated ether transfer

Tags: nethereum, c#

I wish to automate the transfer of ether to a list of people. Assume the list is in a csv. I wrote some code to automate the process.

```
class Program
{
    int nonce = 0;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var account = SetupAccount();
        var recipients = ReadCsv();
        var web3Init = GetConnection();
        nonce = web3.Eth.Transactions.GetTransactionCount.SendRequestAsync(account.Address).Result;
        //var recipients = new List<Records>() { new Records() { Value = 10000000000000000, Address = "0x5CC494843e3f4AC175A5e730c300b011FAbF2cEa" } };
        foreach (var recipient in recipients)
        {
            try
            {
                var web3 = GetConnection();
                var receipt = SendEther(account, recipient, web3).Result;
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Failed");                                        
            }
            Thread.Sleep(30000);
        }
    }

    private static async Task<TransactionReceipt> SendEther(Account account, Records recipient, Web3 web3)
    {
        var transactionPolling = web3.TransactionManager.TransactionReceiptService;

        //var currentBalance = await web3.Eth.GetBalance.SendRequestAsync(account.Address);

        //assumed client is mining already
        //when sending a transaction using an Account, a raw transaction is signed and send using the private key
        return await transactionPolling.SendRequestAndWaitForReceiptAsync(() =>
        {
            var transactionInput = new TransactionInput
            {
                From = account.Address,
                //Gas = new HexBigInteger(25000),
                GasPrice = new HexBigInteger(10 ^ 10),
                To = recipient.Address,
                Value = new HexBigInteger(new BigInteger(recipient.Value)),
                Nonce = nonce
            };
            var txSigned = new Nethereum.Signer.TransactionSigner();
            var signedTx = txSigned.SignTransaction(account.PrivateKey, transactionInput.To, transactionInput.Value, transactionInput.Nonce);
            var transaction = new Nethereum.RPC.Eth.Transactions.EthSendRawTransaction(web3.Client);
            nonce++;
            return transaction.SendRequestAsync(signedTx);
        });
    }

    private static Web3 GetConnection()
    {
        return new Web3("https://mainnet.infura.io");
    }

    private static Account SetupAccount()
    {
        var password = "@Password";
        var accountFilePath = @"filePath";
        return Account.LoadFromKeyStoreFile(accountFilePath, password);
    }

    private static List<Records> ReadCsv()
    {
        string filePath = @"C:\Users\Potti\source\repos\ConversionFiles\XrcfRecipients.csv";
        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            using (StreamReader stream = new StreamReader(filePath))
            {
                CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(stream, new Configuration
                {
                    TrimOptions = TrimOptions.Trim,
                    HasHeaderRecord = true,
                    HeaderValidated = null
                });
                reader.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<RecordMapper>();

                return reader.GetRecords<Records>().ToList();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}

class Records
{
    public string Address { get; set; }

    public decimal Value { get; set; }
}

sealed class RecordMapper : ClassMap<Records>
{
    public RecordMapper()
    {
        Map(x => x.Address).Name("Address");
        Map(x => x.Value).Name("Value");
    }
}
```

How do i modify the process to execute all the transactions at once instead of waiting for each to complete? (Fire and forget) Also, are there any security considerations of doing this?

Comment: Any luck in finding way to bulk process transactions?

Comment: @VinayakM yes. [Here it is](https://github.com/chaitanyapotti/AutomatedEtherTransfer/blob/master/AutomatedEtherTransfer_Windows/Program.cs)

Comment: Thanks, Do you faced nonce issue while sending multiple transactions from same address to list?

Comment: No. TransactionManager handles the nonce